# Number of small eigenvalues for flat unitary bundles

Tags: vector-bundles, sp.spectral-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

It is known that the number of small eigenvalues (eigenvalues less than $1/4$) of the Laplacian on hyperbolic surfaces may be topologically bounded from above. If $X$ is a finite area hyperbolic surface and $\rho:\pi_1(X)\rightarrow U(n)$ is a unitary surface representation, we obtain a rank $n$ flat unitary bundle $E_{\rho}$ over $X$. We may consider the Laplacian acting on sections of $E_{\rho}$. The question I have is the following. Is there is a bound on the number of small eigenvalues in this setting that is of the form $O_X(n)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$?